# Users are not displayed as existing sites when new site collection is created after SharePoint Upgrade from 2016 to SharePoint Subscription edition

Tags: adfs, upgrade-sharepoint

I am currently working on SharePoint server upgrade from 2016 to SharePoint server Subscription Edition. Users are configured using LDAPCP as we are using ADFS authentication and able to see the users as "lastname, firstname" on top right corner as well when they are added to the permission groups. this is all working as expected for the sites and site collections which are restored and mounted using DB. But when I create new site collection, I don't see the users as "lastname, firstname" , it is showing as email "xyz@something.com" . Do i need to run any powershell commands to make it work as existing site collections and sites? I tried to rerun the full synch but still same issue on new site collections.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried psconfig? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d04ae01e-4bb9-4965-8085-37a2eaa9f29c/sharepoint-2016-patching-issue-server-upgrade-requred

`PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures -cmd secureresources -cmd services -install`

If your issue is related to distributed cache: https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2023/02/16/trending-issue-distributed-cache-problems-after-applying-january-2023-cu/

In PowerShell try:

```
Stop-CacheCluster
Set-CacheClusterSecurity -SecurityMode Transport -ProtectionLevel EncryptAndSign
Start-CacheCluster
```